# SLM pulse shaping to delay (and advance) ultrashort pulses in time

Tags: optics, experimental-physics, time, fourier-transform, non-linear-optics

I am trying to replicate some of the experiments discussed in this excellent publication:
[SLM for pulse shaping](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwiLz_qJqb-AAxX1glYBHa-KBR8QFnoECBAQAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fengineering.purdue.edu%2F%7Efsoptics%2Farticles%2FFemtosecond_pulse_shaping-Weiner.pdf&usg=AOvVaw2VSL7idm356iU9WD4-_1IK&opi=89978449)

In particular, I replicated the setup configuration in Figure 14 and I want to use the SLM to delay (and forward) some ultrashort pulses, as shown in Fig 17.
The fundamental piece of theory is reported here from page 14 of the doc:

> Gray-level phase control can be used to accomplish a number of interesting pulse shaping tasks. For example, using the modulator array to impart a linear phase sweep onto the spectrum corresponds in the time domain to pulse position modulation. Pulse position modulation relies on the fact that if f (t) and F(v) are a Fourier transform pair, then the delayed signal f (t-tau) is the Fourier transform of F(v) x exp(-iv tau)
> Thus, a pulse can be retarded (or advanced!) by imposing a linear phase sweep onto its spectrum. The delay t is given by the relation
> [image]

According to this, using a pattern with a positive phase change per pxl like this should introduce a positive delay in time:

[image: pattern for pulse delay]

Therefore, I expect that using a pattern with two opposite linear phase sweeps, half with a positive and half with a negative phase change, should split my incoming pulse into two halves, one that is delayed and the other that is advanced in time:
[image: pattern for two pulses separated in time]

I created these patterns based on my own interpretation of the theory, but since I'm not getting good results I wonder if there is some error or if there's some critical information I'm missing.
Thank you in advance for any help!

Comment: Did you try to work out the inverse Fourier transform of the product of you pulse spectrum and the triangular shape of the function on the SLM?

Comment: Thank you! I tried something following your suggestion, I hope I got it right. I multiplied my spectrum data times a row of one of the patterns above. Then I perform the IFT of the result and display the absolute square, since it's an intensity measurement. The plot indeed shows the spatial pattern that I get after the last lens, and it's very similar to the real measurement, but it doesn't give me any temporal information I think. I don't see how I can tell that the impulse has been delayed or advanced. Am I missing something?

Comment: The IFT should product a time signal. You need to compare the result with the original pulse. How do you measure a time delay in the experiment?

Comment: Sorry for before, now I think I understood it a bit better. I don't have a way to measure the time delay, but for now I'm more interested in writing a code that can simulate the effect of different patterns and number of pixels on a gaussian pulse. Let's say for example that I want to reproduce the results shown in Fig 17 of the article I shared. How would you write the code on python? I wrote something, it works partially but it doesn't show the correct result